# Смс broadcast receiver не срабатывает на Redmi 4x android 7

Tags: java, android, sms, android-broadcastreceiver

Есть Смс broadcast receiver который прекрасно работает на android 10 и выше. Поставил на Redmi 4x с android 7. Пока приложение на экране или в памяти все работает. Очищаю недавно загруженные ресивер не срабатывает. В манифесте

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<receiver
           android:name=".SmsReceiver"
           android:enabled="true"
           android:exported="true"
           android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
           <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
               <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
           </intent-filter>
       </receiver>
```

receiver:

```
...
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: SMS");...
```

Есть идеи в чем проблема? Сам думаю в  MIUI стоит своя утилита которая делает аборт, как узнать?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" /> в манифесте разумеется тоже конечно есть.

Comment: в Redmi много чего не работает. по стандарту  Могу только порекомендовать посмотреть спец. разрешения.